# Backdoor APIs for QA testing - Good or Bad?

Tags: java, rest, testing

Are having APIs for the sake of QA testing a good or bad idea?

We're developing an application from scratch and we've been creating backdoor APIs to ease the jobs for the QAs. These backdoors do things many things like change the date of the server to emulate progression of time etc. I'm quite mixed on this. The number of these backdoors almost rival the real APIs that'll be used in Production.

Is this the recommended approach? The obvious benefit for this is that it makes the lives of the QA must easier. I can see many disadvantages with this also like maintaining the functionality of these test APIs, ensuring that these backdoor APIs are not exposed in production.

If others have used this approach, what are some good means to ensure that these APIs aren't exposed in production?

For those who are against this approach, are there alternatives to making the work for QA easier?

Thanks

Comment: Can't you split your API into two distinctive groups: production and QA. For testing, you can have the QA APIs available. But QA API never gets to production. You can even have a ping-like QA api and you can even add a watch-dog to your production env, which will monitor that resource and if it is there, blows the whistles. Does it make sense ?

Answer (score 1):

If it's not causing QA to miss issues, it's a good thing to do; if you can make their job easier without costs in the future, do it.

However, normally anytime you test one API but *use* another API, you're not actually testing the real API that's going into production.  If QA has a hack around the normal API, they should also be testing the difference between the hack and the real world.

In this case, it sounds like they have helper methods to modify the state, to enable testing.  If there's not a good way to do this otherwise, what they're doing might be pretty darn reasonable... or, at the very least, there may be better ways to spend your time improving things.

But overall; is it regularly (repeatedly) causing them to miss bugs they should have caught?

Answer (score 0):

What build system are you using?

For any software that has any time/scheduling logic, I think it's pretty essential to add a class called SystemClock with a method called 'currentTime().'

In our Android project, we inject the starting time from a Gradle variable, and then we can be sure that there is no way the code can get into production with shifted time (because the variable is defined for the debug build only).

For our iOS release, we were able to use an Extension. That's really a great way to do it because it's only compiled into the test scope. Then it replaces the getCurrentTime method with the shifted one.

The other option you have in the Java world is Aspects. They can be handy for doing mixins in a test build that are not there in production.